# BigQuery Events table missing from some properties

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

My company has 30+ different GA4 properties, and I have set up the data streams and the BigQuery links for all of them.  In BigQuery I have created all of the datasets, but for some reason I can only see the 'events_YYYYMMDD' table on 4 of the properties.  I know that there is a delay sometimes but these are all at least a couple of weeks old so there has been plenty of time for the data to populate.  To the best of my knowledge I followed the exact same steps when setting up the feeds for all of these properties, but something is not allowing my data to flow.  FYI I am in BigQuery sandbox right now, but our data does not approach any of the limitations that I have read about.  Any troubleshooting suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried deleting and recreating the data streams and the BigQuery links for some of the non-working properties, but I still cannot see the data.

Comment: Would you please add some photos showing your settings

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your response.  I have actually resolved this issue, the problem was that the service account did not have the BigQuery Data Owner permission for those properties where the data was missing.  I don't recall setting them up any differently but I must have done something different to cause that.